# Webdeploy not publishing App_GlobalResources folder with resource files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, webdeploy

When I publish my MVC Web Application using WebDeploy (using msbuild) via my buildserver, the App_GlobalResources does not end up in the root of the application, and I get an error locating resources

```
The resource object with classname 'Site' and key 'SiteMapAddRequest' was not found - System.Web.SiteMapNode.GetExplicitResourceString(..
```

The project is configured to only deploy the required files. The App_GlobalResources folder does end up being copied into my bin directory, probably because the resource file it contains is set to `Embedded Resource` and `Copy to Output Directory`. I would like to avoid setting the project to publish *all* files to the server if possible. The app runs correctly inside visual studio as the App_GlobalResources folder is present in the root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the properties of my resources file in the App_GlobalResources folder to the defaults for a new file and it worked.

```
Build Action: Content
Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy
Custom Tool: GlobalResourceProxyGenerator
Custom Tool Namespace: <empty>
```